# Why can't Jquery access an imported element on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a change that lists records from a database, my main page uses a second page to load information from it. I want the user to be able to click an 'x' and be able to delete the record.

So i have my main page 'index.php' and i have the loader page that is called 'get_results.php'

So when i load index.php, the JS loads and then goes to get_results.php and then displays the output on the screen, however, when i click the 'x' to try and delete a section it doesn't work. To add to that, i have run the JS script on the get_result.php page and the deleting works just fine.

I can't figure out how to get around this, i assume that it's because the new data (get_results) is being loaded after the index.php document is loaded.

I thought about changing when this data is load but i will still have the same problem because users can click a button and it gets rid of the data and puts new data there.

When the doc is read i run this:

```
$(".search_results_container").load("get_results.php?service_type=auto #results_output");
```

This loads the new data into it's container.

Then when the clicks the X it should run this code:

```
$(".delete_result").on("click", function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();

    var result_id = $(this).data("delete-id");

    // post data to delete page
    $.post("delete_results.php?action=delete&result_id=" + result_id, function( data ){
        // Out delete data
        console.log(data);
       // Refresh list
    } );

});
```

And this is the HTML that is being loaded into the container

```
<ul class="data_list" id="result_list">
<li>
    <div class="result_info">
        <a href="?action=edit_result&result_id=5" class="update_links">
            <h2>
                Test data 1
                <small>Testing</small>
            </h2>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="result_delete_icon">
        <a href="?result_id=5&action=delete" class="delete_result" data-delete-id="5">
            <i class="fa fa-times" style="float: right;"></i>
        </a>    
    </div>
</li>
<div class="result_info">
        <a href="?action=edit_result&result_id=5" class="update_links">
            <h2>
                Test data 1
                <small>Testing</small>
            </h2>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="result_delete_icon">
        <a href="?result_id=5&action=delete" class="delete_result" data-delete-id="5">
            <i class="fa fa-times" style="float: right;"></i>
        </a>    
    </div>  
</li>
```

I really don't know how to get this working, i'm thinking maybe something needs to be refreshed because it seems like Jquery isn't finding the elements in the dom, but i thought that if i reference the element each time, instead of storing it in a var it would walk through the DOM again to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't doing what you think it's doing:

```
$(".delete_result").on("click", function( e ){
```

This is invoking the selector `".delete_result"` *once*, identifying the elements which exist *at that time*, and attaching the click handler to those elements.  Handlers are attached to *elements*, not to *selectors*.  So any elements added to the page after this code executes won't have click handlers attached to them.

Instead, you're looking to do this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete_result", function( e ){
```

This still executes only *once*, but attaches the handler to `document` (which is unchanging during the life of the DOM).  Indeed, any common unchanging parent element in the hierarchy will work in place of `document`.  The second selector, `".delete_result"`, is used *on each event* to filter events from selected child elements.  Thus, any element added to the `document` later in the life of the DOM will still "bubble up" its click event to `document` and be identified by that second selector.

For more examples and information, I've [written about this before](http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2014/03/on-on-or-event-delegation-explained.html).

Comment: Excellent answer, i can see where i've done wrong now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `delegate` your event http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete_result",function( e ){...
```

Comment: Thanks, One question though, Does this go inside the "$(document).ready(function(){"?

Comment: Yes it does. Inside for sure.